# SQL Oracle - Can not create a view (ORA-00998 ERROR)

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create view with select and count/order by. Select lonely works but when I add command CREATE VIEW pocetpresov AS it shows me a error. (ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias )
Where is problem please?

```
CREATE VIEW pocetpresov AS
SELECT mesto, COUNT( mesto ) FROM klient GROUP BY mesto
HAVING
    COUNT( mesto )> 1
ORDER BY
    mesto;
```

Comment: Obviously need to alias `COUNT( mesto )` which appears on the select list( *you must use aliases if the query contains expressions rather than only column names* from [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8004.htm)  )

Comment: [ORA-00998](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm#1004903): **Cause**: An expression or function was used in a CREATE VIEW statement, but no corresponding column name was specified. When expressions or functions are used in a view, all column names for the view must be explicitly specified in the CREATE VIEW statement.

**Action**: Enter a column name for each column in the view in parentheses after the view name.

Comment: I suggest naming this expression with a column alias.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a name to your COUNT column to get this query worked as a VIEW -

```
CREATE VIEW pocetpresov AS
SELECT mesto, COUNT( mesto ) cnt_mesto 
  FROM klient 
 GROUP BY mesto
HAVING COUNT( mesto )> 1
 ORDER BY mesto;
```